# Remover ponto e vírgula de uma string JS

Tags: javascript, angular

Olá, gostaria de saber se há algo errado nessa função que não me deixa retirar o ponto e a vírgula da string. O que acontece é que eu tenho um input que, ao receber o valor digitado ele formata o texto digitado para o padrão BRL

```
console.log(moneyMask(1579846));

saída: 
15.798,46;
```

Até aí, tudo certo mas se eu acrescentar mais dígitos a saída fica assim:

```
console.log(moneyMask(15.798,4656));

saída: 
15.798,46,56;
```

Aqui está o código da função:

```
static moneyMask(value) {
        let tmp = value + '';
        tmp.replace(/[\D]+/g, '');
        tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{2})$/g, ',$1');
        if (tmp.length > 6) {
            tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2}$)/g, '.$1,$2');
        }
        if (tmp.length > 9) {
            tmp = tmp.replace(/([0-9]{3}).([0-9]{3}),([0-9]{2})$/g, '.$1.$2,$3');
        }
        return tmp;
    }
```

Notem que o `tmp.replace(/[\D]+/g, '');` deveria limpar o ponto e a vírgula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatação de números não é algo que você precise inventar a roda, a não ser que você realmente queira. Além de várias classes prontas, você pode usar os métodos nativos do JS para fazer isso, já suportados pelos browsers com suporte a PT-BR.

Exemplo:

```
const number = 123456.789;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
// expected output: "123.456,79 €"

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', { style: 'currency', currency: 'JPY' }).format(number));
// expected output: "￥123,457"

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', { maximumSignificantDigits: 3 }).format(number));
// expected output: "1,23,000"
```

Uma boa leitura que vai ajudar muito você:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução simplesmente morrendo de procurar finalmente encontrei uma que substituisse:

```
const v = ((value.replace(/\D/g, '') / 100).toFixed(2) + '').split('.');

        const m = v[0].split('').reverse().join('').match(/.{1,3}/g);

        for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            m[i] = m[i].split('').reverse().join('') + '.';
        }

        const r = m.reverse().join('');

        return r.substring(0, r.lastIndexOf('.')) + ',' + v[1];
```

Comment: "morrendo de procurar" apenas 25 minutos após perguntar?
https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas

Comment: "apenas 25 minutos após peguntar" como se eu tivesse procurando depois que fiz a pergunta '-' Passei a manha inteira procurando. Se não vai comentar algo construtivo não comenta